# How to assign my Form1 frm variable to the existing/loaded form object?

Tags: c#, winforms, object, syntax, instantiation

So I have a handler that contains the following code:

```
    private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        Form1 frm = //want to set 'frm' to the existing, instantiated form1 already running.
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting(); //stores the char that fired the event into 'indata'
        if (indata == "\r") //check to see if char received indicates end of measurement, yes tells main form to add measurement, no tells to add char to string
        {
            frm.pendingMeasurement = true;
            MessageBox.Show(myString);
        }
        else
            myString += indata;
    }
```

on line 4 I'm creating a form1 object and I want to set it to the existing, already running, form1 object. How do I access that object syntax-wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `Form1` behave somewhat like a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern):

Add a static `Form1` member to `Form1`:

```
public static Form1 instance;
```

Set it in `Form1`'s constructor:

```
instance = this;
```

And then access it in your code like this:

```
Form1.instance
```